# 'Page not found' error on my controller for my NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am coding in C# on Visual Studio 2019, I am working on a 2019 MacBook. My app is a NET Core Web API 2.2. My controller is a API Controller with actions using Entity Framework.

I ran my app before I started the project and it worked fine, I have connected to my sql server, made my migrations and updated my database. When I run the app without debugging it works fine for the values controller (https://localhost:5001/api/values), but when I type in the name of my 'Loan controller' (https://localhost:5001/api/loan) it gets the HTTP error 'This localhost page can’t be found No web page was found for the web address: https://localhost:5001/api/loan'

Here is the code for the LoanController.cs file

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebAPI.Models;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class LoanController : Controller
    {
        private readonly LoanContext _context;

        public LoanController(LoanContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Loan
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Loans.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Loan/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var loan = await _context.Loans
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.LoanCode == id);
            if (loan == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(loan);
        }

        // GET: Loan/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Loan/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("LoanCode,LoanID,BorrowerName,FundingAmount,RepaymentAmount")] Loan loan)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(loan);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(loan);
        }

        // GET: Loan/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var loan = await _context.Loans.FindAsync(id);
            if (loan == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(loan);
        }

        // POST: Loan/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("LoanCode,LoanID,BorrowerName,FundingAmount,RepaymentAmount")] Loan loan)
        {
            if (id != loan.LoanCode)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(loan);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!LoanExists(loan.LoanCode))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(loan);
        }

        // GET: Loan/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var loan = await _context.Loans
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.LoanCode == id);
            if (loan == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(loan);
        }

        // POST: Loan/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var loan = await _context.Loans.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Loans.Remove(loan);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool LoanExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Loans.Any(e => e.LoanCode == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the ValuesController.cs file

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs file

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using WebAPI.Models;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddDbContext<LoanContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Launchsetting.JSON file

```
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:41196",
      "sslPort": 44395
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

above

```
public class LoanController : Controller
```

So that it can locate the Loan route. This is already in place for your ValuesController.

See [Microsoft docs - Token replacement in route templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area)

[controller] is replaced by the name of your controller ('Loan') as the routing is set up and so this then matches the route 'api/loan'.